# Wordpress Site not Connecting thru online Cron Job Service

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am running a wordpress site and using an online cron job service to connect.
When i connect thru the service im getting "**HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found**" error.
This is the cron job link im using:
http://www.moongot.com/wp-content/plugins/WPFanMachineBasic/auto.php

This is the output:

> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.22 Pragma: no-cache Date: Sat, 14 Apr 2018
>   22:00:59 GMT Content-Length: 4 Server: Apache/2 Set-Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=3ef1b912c68e0502d03caccb87e0858b; path=/ Expires: Wed, 11
>   Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate,
>   max-age=0 X-Endurance-Cache-Level: 2 Content-Type: text/html;
>   charset=UTF-8
>
> DONE

Comment: Don't worry, I get a 404 to so it's not your cron job.

Comment: That URL is generating a 404, even though it outputs `DONE`. You'll need to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same via cURL:

```
curl -I http://www.moongot.com/wp-content/plugins/WPFanMachineBasic/auto.php

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sat, 14 Apr 2018 22:29:13 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 863
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=30
Server: Apache/2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.22
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=2df00eb1132bf607a708d00aee845f8a; path=/
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Wed, 02 Aug 2017 19:17:35 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

and in Chrome:

[image]

So you'll want to figure out why your `auto.php` file is spitting out a 404 header.